# Fixed sorting using cdkDrag in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I am trying to prevent moving item which is disabled during sorting using Angular CDK drag-drop

```
<div cdkDropList class="example-list" 
[cdkDropListSortPredicate]="sortPredicateForDisableItem(items)"
(cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
<div
  class="example-box"
  *ngFor="let item of items"
  cdkDrag
  [cdkDragDisabled]="item.disabled">{{item.value}}</div>
</div>
```

In Component,

```
public items = [
    {value: 'I can be dragged 1', disabled: false},
    {value: 'I can be dragged 2 ', disabled: false},
    {value: 'I cannot  be dragged and i want to be fixed in position 3', disabled: true},
    {value: 'I can be dragged 4 ', disabled: false,dinesh: 'kumar'},
  ];
sortPredicateForDisableItem(items: any) {
    // This logic fails to prevent moving disabled item
    return function(index: number, item: CdkDrag, drop: CdkDropList){
    return items[index].disabled === false
    }
  }
```

Before sorting

[image]

After sorting, Item3 shifting to new position and it can not be fixed in position

[image]

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ah78xx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-sort-predicate-example.ts)

Can item which has disabled property can be fixed in position where it belongs? Expectation is , Disabled item always retain in same index/position during sorting. Please advise

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply "lock" the disabled item in place, since e.g. dragging something from index 0 to index 3 will affect indexes of all items in between. What you have to do is actually not allow drag actions that would change the index of the disabled item.

So, what you need to do is:

1. Load items and sort them in correct order.
2. Change the drag-drop logic to check if the action is allowed
3. Either disallow the action, or modify it's effects by your desired logic

I've forked your stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ah78xx-j5vpwc) and prepared a simple solution. I haven't tested it thoroughly, but it should give you basic idea how it should work.

What it does is basically writing custom `moveItemInArray` function based on the original one from [here](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/7a6549fb11a108f351aa4bf2a3686a75bdbc642c/src/cdk/drag-drop/drag-utils.ts#L15):

```
  private moveItemInArrayIfAllowed(
    array: any[],
    fromIndex: number,
    toIndex: number
  ): void {
    const from = this.clamp(fromIndex, array.length - 1);
    const to = this.clamp(toIndex, array.length - 1);

    if (from === to) {
      return;
    }

    const target = array[from];
    const delta = to < from ? -1 : 1;

    const affectedItems = array.filter((item, index) =>
      delta > 0 ? index >= from && index <= to : index >= to && index <= from
    );

    // If any of the items affected by the index changes is disabled
    // don't move any of the items.
    if (affectedItems.some((i) => i.disabled)) {
      return;
    }

    for (let i = from; i !== to; i += delta) {
      array[i] = array[i + delta];
    }

    array[to] = target;
  }

  private clamp(value: number, max: number): number {
    return Math.max(0, Math.min(max, value));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and yes its worked after drop. This could also be solution. I was trying to use predicate event before drop happened

Comment: Your solution helped me alot! I managed to fix the position before reordering, have a look and feel free to update you answer where you see fit: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ah78xx-tcopmc) - @mymotherland FYI